# Maven in Netbeans always downloading dependency every run file

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I have a problem with Maven project in netbeans. I am new to maven so maybe this is a general question. The problem is, every time I run the main class file (Shift+F6), the console will display the downloading from the repo. I notice that this makes me slower because if I just change some line, I will need to wait the maven to re download every dependency again. Is it possible to run file without maven re downloading all dependency?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the standard behaviour of Maven. First of all, check whether Maven is really downloading the jar files and not only metadata or poms. If so, it can have several reasons:

- You activated Update-Snapshots in your build (`-u`). This downloads all SNAPSHOT dependencies in every build (if they changed).
- Your update period for SNAPSHOTs is set to a very low value (the standard value, which is good for most purposes, is 1 day). Same effect as above.
- Your local repository (user/.m2/repository) is broken. Delete it and try again.

Comment: Is there an option not only for snapshots to be downloaded?

Comment: I mean that when I use the option -u maven does not download the dependencies that are declared in pom.xml.

Comment: @zygimantus: I still don't get it. Standard behaviour of maven is to reload SNAPSHOTS every night and keep release versions forever. If you use -u maven reloads the SNAPSHOTS in every build (but not the release versions).